# What can I use for something like Google web analytics for a Drupal website?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for my site to use web analytics so I will be able to track inside my backend on whats going on inside my web.

I am looking for something like Google Analytics but just on Drupal.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal have the [Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) too

> Adds the Google Analytics web statistics tracking system to your
>   website.

also install the [Google Analytics Reports](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module to track within the site itself.

> Google Analytics Reports provides graphical reporting of your site's
>   tracking data. Graphical reports include a dashboard widget for
>   admins, a small path-based report in blocks, and a full path-based
>   report.

Comment: can i track the google analytics on my drupal ?without go to the google analytics web?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports To track reports on drupal portal...

Comment: @user26893 see my updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For info related to visitors of a website (registered users is a subset of them), consider the [visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module as a possible alternative. Refer to its [community docu](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) for some more details.

It also support charting of those data (a typical related requirement ...).

**Be aware**: I'm the [new](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380441#comment-9651615) maintainer of it.